# Displaying text one after another Android

Tags: java, android-studio, handler

im trying to display some text after another ends, im using a handler with a switch within a "for", so for each rotation waits 5sec and prints the next text, well thats my theory but the only thing i get its the program waits 5sec then prints all the texts at the same time, any help would be appreciated.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    int finalI = i;
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            switch (finalI){
                case 0: twChoice1.animateText("text 1"); break;
                case 1: twChoice2.animateText("text 2"); break;
                case 2: twChoice3.animateText("text 3"); break;
                case 3: twChoice4.animateText("text 4"); break;
            }

        }
    }, 5000);
}
```

Comment: The problem with this is that you're posting all the messages at the same time.  The answer below using TimerTask does it better.  The other option would be to either have each Runnable post the one that comes after it, so the delay is cumulative, or to make the delay 5000*(i+1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to work with Timer and TimerTask (import those two).

```
private int messageIndex = 0;
private TextView[] txtViewsArray = {twChoice1, twChoice2, twChoice3, twChoice4};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    displayMessages();
}

private void displayMessages() {
    Timer timer = new Timer();

    TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            if (index >= txtViewsArray.length) messageIndex = 0;
            txtViewsArray[messageIndex].animateText("text" + (messageIndex + 1).toString());
            messageIndex++;
        }
    };

    timer.schedule(timerTask, 0, 5000);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Raphael, i got it working with the Timer and a few modification, because i cant use an array with twChoice.animateText , but its working now.